# Link Icloud with rails web allication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, icloud

As like oAuth we can synchronise users authentication information with third party applications or websites, I want to integrate iCloud calendar service with my rails application. From where on button click user is asked to provide their iCloud credentials and after verifying user my rails app should allow that user to access his iCalendar events(Dynamic event generation).

I already tried to add iCloud calendar account with chronofy but it's not recognising my **APP-SPECIFIC-PASSWORD**.

So is this possible, preferably with some kind of oAuth setup as we do it with Google Calendar? or are their any API which can carry out my task, if so where can I find documentation on the API?

Comment: Hi Smit, if you require support for Cronofy its best to reach us at support@cronofy.com with the details of the account.

Answer (score 0):

Apple do not provide a public OAuth mechanism for iCloud so its not possible to access their API directly